# Is copying files between two different file systems slower than between the same file systems?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, ext4

I was wondering if copying files between different file systems (for example from ext4 to ntfs) is slower than copying to the same file system (from ext4 to ext 4).

I also would like to know how does this apply for cases of ext4, btfrs and ntfs.

Comment: No, unless you are copying to is slower by itself. NTFS is.

Comment: @ilkhd I don't understand what you mean. Regardless of filesystem, a real copy of a file (i.e. without CoW or symlink) depends on the speed of the underlying device. Copying from NTFS in a fast drive to ext4 in a slower drive is **always** slow. NTFS is not a slow filesystem either. For example tiny files are contained in the MFT itself, hence will take instantly to accessing/creating it. In general speed depends on file size, system load at the time and fragmentation state of the drive